# Codeigniter dynamic field in form validation with original form validation array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have set in form_validation.php the array that validates my form.

However, I have some dynamic fields that may (or may not) be inserted into this array.

So I use the following code, I want to know if this is the right way

```
if($this->form_validation->run('agenda_de_contatos')){
    if($this->input->post('contato[]')!=""){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->input->post('contato[]'), 'USC_CONTATO', 'trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->input->post('contato_tipo[]'), 'USC_TIPO', 'trim|xss_clean');
    }

    if($this->form_validation->run()){...}
```

Or if I can somehow add itens to the original array and then run form validation?

Thank's,

Comment: You would be better to still maintain some control over the field types users are allowed create dynamically. Then you could iterate over the fields, compare them to a white list of allowed types they can create, then apply validation rules for that type. For instance [dynamic_field][**phone**] or [dynamic_field][**fax**] you would apply a set of pre made rules for those types.

Comment: Another way to do it - you can run more then one form validation. that might be more flexible and cleaner. Also fyi xss_clean on input is being discouraged - they are encouraging xss clean on output. this will work in codeigniter 2, but xss_clean as part of form validation will error in codeigniter 3. am learning about this myself - here is recent thread on forum that goes into it: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61695.html